# IE 11 ignores font-size

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11, font-size

In IE11 the `font-size` of my navigation bar is much much smaller than in other browsers.

In my CSS file, I set `body { font-size:16px; }` which I would like to make a default `font-size` for the document.

For all other elements I use `em` units.

I set `font-size:1.5em` for `<a>` in my navbar, which should be `24px`, but IE11 ignores that and the font-size is only `16px`. Same thing happens to some other text on the website (`h1`, `h2`, `span`).

When I inspect the element I see that IE11 shows `1.5em` size as the one that is assign to it, but the result of calculation is only `16px`.
Other browsers (including Edge) displays the website properly.

```css
* {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: normal;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  color: #666;
  font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}
nav#top {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}
nav#top ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}
nav#top ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
nav#top ul li a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 30px 10px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #060;
}
```

```html
<nav id="top">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="page1/">Label 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page1/">Label 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page1/">Label 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page1/">Label 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page1/">Label 1</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I googled about `font-size:100% !important` and similar solution, but didn't find anything that works.

Comment: Your code works perfectly in IE11 , check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/f1jxe1hn/)

Comment: Have you tried setting your `16px` font-size on your `html` element and then using the `rem` unit? That should avoid any standard behaviour (1.5rem is _always_ 1.5 times the `html`-rem unit)

Comment: check out http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/

Comment: Well, thank you. It seems that IE11 on my PC is not properly configured and for some reason it ignores CSS `font-size` setting. Even if I set to `20em` or use pixels ie. `40px` the font doesn't change the size.  How to restore default configuration for IE11?

Comment: I've found it. Had checked the option "Ignore font-sizes specified on webpages" in Internet Options -> Accessibility. Now works perfectly. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
nav#top ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family: "Arimo",sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 30px 10px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #060;
}
```

Comment: Why should he try that? Be more specific about your answer :)

Comment: Using pixels unit is not what I would like to do. Anyway it doesn't work anyway. It seems my IE11 is not properly configured.

Answer (score 0):

This will not comply with every use case, but it's the way that has reduced my headaches dramatically.

To achieve an overall good cross browser experience, I would suggest that you in general remove font-sizes from the body tag and let the browsers do their magic.

Although - at first glance - it seems that you might loose control over the design, I have learned that you get more consistent results if you remove most of the font-size properties.